# unicode-math package broken without \setmathfont when compiled by XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

After I updated TeXLive 2018 yesterday, I got the following error message when I use XeLaTeX to compile my file.

```
xelatex.exe> Runaway argument?
xelatex.exe> 76543210\q_stop newline - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[0.9999\ETC.
xelatex.exe> ! File ended while scanning use of \__iow_wrap_end_chunk:w.
xelatex.exe> <inserted text> 
xelatex.exe>                 \par
```

After checking the code, I found this error happens with TeXLive and MiKTeX with XeLaTeX. When I switch to LuaLaTeX or use `\setmathfont` to set the font, the error disappear. The following is the minimal example in my computer. Does anyone know what might cause this? Or this is a bug in `unicode-math`? Thanks : )

```
%% LyX 2.3.1-1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
~
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a bug in l3kernel. It has already been updated on ctan but miktex will need to catch up with it.

Comment: You can download `http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel.tds.zip` from ctan, unpack it somewhere outside miktex and attach its root as a new root in the miktex console. That should keep you going until miktex installs the new version.

Comment: No error with the just updated `l3kernel`. It was a bug that has been removed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is solved updating the TeX distribution

Comment: To Ulrike Fischer, I have followed your instruction to add l3kernel.tds as a new root directory, but I still get the same error. May I confirm how to make sure MikTeX use the new l3kernel.tds, and not the original one? Thanks : )

Comment: @Yu-TsungTai You can update from a more update-to-date mirror. Generally, It is not advised to update the distribution during an important project.

Comment: @ Zeping Lee I have just updated the l3kernel package in MiKTeX, but I still need my work around to compile. Moreover, I can compile my document without installing l3kernel package. Maybe MiKTeX put the function of l3kernel in other place? Since I have alread upgraded, and  MiKTeX has no option to downgrade, maybe I will just keep my work around right now... >"<

Comment: I found the problem wasn't resolved because I only updated l3kernel package in the system path not in my personal path... orz